# nodepie function not using values in data frame

Tags: r, insets, ggtree

Q: The pie charts produced using nodepie within ggtree is not using the numbers from a specified data frame. [SOLVED see end of post]

I have a large tree, and the code for making the plot is below:

```
p1<-ggtree(tree, ladderize = TRUE, branch.length = "none", right = TRUE)
```

I have a matrix that I've modified which has posterior probabilities of five traits for each of four nodes, where each row equals 1 and includes a 'node' column:

```
nodeTest<-data.frame(A=c(0.0958211092749001,0.0637862609375507,0.463996386876187,0.00165395365974673),B=c(0.390789314936616,0.0528965215595085,0.23601740209132,0.00195511257329542),C=c(0.0531783209956143,0.704308173828317,0.0163010480752175,0.0740274150681192),D=c(0.459159498364088,0.0980025477225612,0.283044455979883,0.00248691661024461),E=c(0.00105175642878233,0.0810064959520626,0.000640706977391879,0.919876602088594))
namesTest<-c("349","350","358","405")
nodeTest<-cbind(nodeTest,namesTest)
colnames(nodeTest)<-c("A","B","C","D","E","node")
nodeTest1<-as.data.frame(nodeTest)
```

So the data frame looks like this:

```
                      A                   B                  C                   D                   E     node
349  0.0958211092749001   0.390789314936616 0.0531783209956143   0.459159498364088 0.00105175642878233   349
350  0.0637862609375507  0.0528965215595085  0.704308173828317  0.0980025477225612 0.0810064959520626    350
358   0.463996386876187    0.23601740209132 0.0163010480752175   0.283044455979883 0.000640706977391879  358
405 0.00165395365974673 0.00195511257329542 0.0740274150681192 0.00248691661024461 0.919876602088594     405
```

When I do the below code, I get the attached image with four pie charts.

```
piesTest<-nodepie(nodeTest1,cols = 1:5)
inset(p1,piesTest, width = 0.035,height = 0.035)
```

[image]

The pie charts are at the correct nodes, but the wedges 1) are all equal to each other instead of reflecting what is in `nodeTest1` data frame, and 2) the order of those wedges is different, judging from the color orders in each. I am new to using ggtree, and can run other examples with the pie charts matching what is in the data frame, but when I set up my data in the same way, I get different results. Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: I have figured it out. When I did `cbind` with the full data set, it changed everything to a character. I had to set each column `as.numeric` within the data frame, and then it worked.